# How to create an instance of IntList?

Tags: java

I try to use a package of collections called fastutil, but I'm not able to create an instance of `IntList`.

I've tried using the default constructor call, but it did not work.

```
IntList foo = new IntList();
```

How can I create a new instance of `IntList` ?

Comment: Please post your code. Otherwise it is hard to help.

Comment: IntList is an interface, which cant be instantiated (source: http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/ints/IntList.html)
IntArrayList is the class implementing this interface, try to instantiate that.

Comment: @Uli I just want to create a variable! it should be similar to normal java collection but it seems not :(

Comment: @pvytykac ahhhh, I think this solves the problem! so stupid :')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IntList` is an interface. So you can't directly initialize it, you need to initialize an Object that implements the interface in order to have an instance of `IntList`.

Here an example :

```
IntList foo = new IntArrayList();
```

You might want to see [IntArrayList constructors](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/ints/IntArrayList.html) for possible instantiation.

Note that all known classes that implement `IntList` are

- AbstractIntList
- AbstractIntList.IntSubList
- IntArrayList
- IntLists.EmptyList
- IntLists.Singleton
- IntLists.SynchronizedList
- IntLists.UnmodifiableList